# Nodejs: npm throwing error when using monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ubuntu-14.04

I'm building a NodeJS app using ExpressJS framework.

I'm trying to use monk to connect to MongoDB

```
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:3000/nodeauth');
```

When I do `npm start` , I'm getting the following error:

```
npm start

> jsblog@0.0.0 start /home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog
> node ./bin/www

/home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:33
  var skinClassName = 'Skin' + NativeClass.name;
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at makeSkinClass (/home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:33:43)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/grid.js:6:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/db.js:22:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/mongo_client.js:5:14)

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/node-v5.7.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/node-v5.7.1-linux-x64/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jsblog@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jsblog@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jsblog package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jsblog
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jsblog
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/bytegeek/Codes/Expressprojects/jsblog/npm-debug.log
```

I already have a MongoDB database `nodeauth` and also have some contents in it. `mongod` service is also running.

P.S: If I remove the above two lines of codes and do `npm start` , there is no error and I'm able to see the express welcome page at `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Check your MongoDB port where it is running. if you did not change the default port , it should be  `http://localhost:27017/nodeauth`

I think your app is running on `3000` port. so, check the `mongod` port and check again.

Comment: mongodb is running on 27017. but `localhost:27017/nodeauth` didn't help. Still same error is showing up. And yes, app is running on `3000` port.

Answer (score 0):

omit he port number for monk module. try this way.

```
var db = require('monk')('localhost/nodeauth');
```